# Form posting does not work

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble to post a html form. I am posting one form and getting the post value to my variable and then I am post this form but this form is not posting.

HTML code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="widget-box">
            <div class="widget-title"> <span class="icon"> <i class="icon-user"></i> </span>
                <h5>Amc details</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
              <div class="controls controls-row">
                  <div class="control-group span3">
                      <label for="normal" class="control-label">Installation Date<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                      <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="amc-ins-date" data-date="01-02-2016" name="amc-ins-date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"  class="datepicker span12"  placeholder="Enter installation date">
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="control-group span3">
                      <label for="normal" class="control-label">Start Date<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                      <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="amc-start-date" data-date="01-02-2016" name="amc-start-date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" placeholder="Enter amc start date"  class="datepicker span12 ins-date">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group span3">
                      <label class="control-label">End Date<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                      <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="amc-end-date" data-date="01-02-2016" name="amc-end-date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" placeholder="Enter amc end date"  class="datepicker span12 ins-date">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group span3">
                      <label class="control-label">Amount<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                      <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="amc-amount" name="amc-amount" class="span12" placeholder="Enter amc amount">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <input style="float:right" type="submit" name="amc-installation" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
                </div>
      </form>
```

PHP code:

```
 // i have submitted a form here and its posted
// installation details
    $mc_serial = $_POST['mc-serial'];
    $mc_model = $_POST['mc-model'];
    $contract_type = $_POST['contract_type'];
    $no_of_copies = $_POST['no-of-copies'];
    $spare_part = join(",",$_POST['spare-part']);
    $eng_name = $_POST['eng-name'];
    $review = $_POST['review'];
    // check if the machine already exits
    if(IsMachine($mc_serial,$con)){
         echo msgIsMachine();
         exit();
    }
    if($contract_type == 'AMC'){
      require './forms/amc.php'; // this is the html i have shown above
    } elseif ($contract_type == 'ASC') {
      require './forms/asc.php';
    } elseif ($contract_type == '4C') {
      require './forms/4c.php';
    } elseif ($contract_type == 'RENTAL') {
      require './forms/rental.php';
    } elseif ($contract_type == 'WARRANTY') {
      require './forms/warranty.php';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['amc-installation']) && !empty($_POST['amc-installation'])){
      echo "posted";
      var_dump($_POST);($_POST);
    }
```

The output of `var_dump` is `NULL`. I don't get any problem.

Comment: What is the filename of this file?

Comment: that form is in a separate fine and i included it in the file where i have php code

Comment: And the main file has a `.php` extension right?

Comment: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` What does this resolve to? Does it definitely point to the PHP file which is intended to receive the data?

Comment: yes it has a .php ext . i have updated my question. please have a look

Comment: ok. this makes no sense. You echo the form, but then _immediately_ check for values returned from it within the same script execution. You have to wait for the user to post the form back before you can check the submitted values. This would be a separate postback, and therefore a separate execution context for the PHP. So the code to check needs to be in a separate section (or file) which is triggered by the submission of the second form.

Comment: wait - if the form is a different file, why are you using `PHP_SELF`?

Comment: `require` copies the  content of the file to another right? so it does not mean that its the same file right now ? @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: not really - it just includes it, you want to use the full absolute path for form actions

Comment: i think you are right. i have to do that.@ADyson

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs using PHP_SELF will generate the current URL, regardless which file it was included from. That's not really the issue. The issue is about request lifecycle - the code is not waiting for the user to post back the form before trying to read the values from it.

Comment: @ADyson yeah I know that's why I'm confused as to why it's being used haha if the php page is a separate script, even if it's being included will always be null because it posts to itself and refreshes the document

Comment: i have solved problem by executing the action in separate file. thank you guys. :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs in this case the result of PHP_SELF will be the URL that the code is triggered by. Let's say that was "test.php". The result of PHP_SELF will be "http://www.example.com/test.php" _not_ "http://www.example.com/amc.php" even though the PHP_SELF command is inside amc.php. It responds to the current context, not the filename. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @ADyson ah I see, so it doesn't read the url for it? it goes from context?

Comment: yes it reads the URL. But the URL was not amc.php, amc.php was only _included_ in the currently executing script. So let's say the main script which was requested by the browser was "test.php", then PHP_SELF will output "test.php", even if it is called inside an included script. Remember that PHP can potentially include scripts which are not even directly addressable via HTTP (if their location on disk is outside the website root), so it would not make sense to have it output the filename of the included script. There are other ways to get that value if it's needed.

Comment: thank you @ADyson learn a awesome thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You echo the second form (during the script which responds to the submission of the first one), but then *immediately* check for values returned from it within the same script execution. You have to wait for the user to post the form back before you can check the submitted values. This would be a separate postback, and therefore a separate execution context for the PHP.

So the code to check the values from the second form needs to be in a separate section (or file) which is triggered by the submission of the second form.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['amc-installation']) && !empty($_POST['amc-installation'])){
  echo "posted";
  var_dump($_POST);
}
```

You should use `$_POST` not `$POST`.

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: OP's `var_dump($_POST)` was using the correct name. so this does nto explain it being NULL

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes you are Right, let me run his code at my side

Comment: @NiravJoshi your code looks like the other answer now :D

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yes You are right :D after read RiggsFolly's Comment i suddenly realize that i also make a mistake, Becuase he used corrent $_POST in var_dump

Answer (score 0):

There's no `$POST` in PHP you should use `$_POST` instead :

```
if(isset($_POST['amc-installation']) && !empty($_POST['amc-installation'])){
   echo "posted";
   var_dump($_POST);
}
```

**NOTE :** You should place the `var_dump($_POST);` inside the `if` statement, so it will be trrigered just after the submit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP's `var_dump($_POST)` was using the correct name. so this does nto explain it being NULL

Comment: i am sorry its a typing mistake. i actually used $_POST

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you get `NULL` in the first chargement of the page because there's no `$_POST` values submited.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but does not work. is it because i posted one form and then i included this form in the same page after that i am submitting the form

Comment: @MofiqulIslm What are you saying? Are you using FORM inside FORM?

Comment: Do you mean you've added the form dynamically? please show us how you include it.